Arm64 Issue with Expo Module Dependency
I've been stuck on an architecture-related error for a couple of days and could use some help. I'm creating an expo module to wrap a third-party dependency as described here: https://docs.expo.dev/modules/third-party-library/. I'm trying to wrap OpenCV, so I added s.dependency 'OpenCV' to my .podspec file. However, when I try to build a simulator, I get an error at ExpoModulesCore-Swift.h that says unsupported Swift architecture. If I manually go into the example project and exclude arm64 architecture for simulators from all the pods, then the project runs. This is great, but if I ever publish the project, then users would have to manually perform the same exclusion.
Any ideas would be welcome. Thanks. (edited)
Things I have tried so far:

I tried using several different dynamic framework pod versions of OpenCV, but I get a similar error. Even weirder, I can't get those to run if I perform the arm64 exclusion.

I have tried to add these lines to the .podspec file:
s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }



